# Enlarge / Shrink UIImage with sound capture Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, button, audio

Do you know a library / trick that would allow me to create an animation of my button (round circle) depending on the voice?

I have a music application in which my record button is round and I would like it to enlarge or shrink according to the intensity of the song.

Let's say it looks a bit like the Shazam button without the waves.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
func animateRecordButton() {

    if let button = self.recordButton {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {

            if self.scaledDown {
                button.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            } else {
                button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.amplitude, y: self.amplitude)
            }
        }, completion: { (done) in

            self.scaledDown = !self.scaledDown

            if !self.recordingStopped {
                //Generate new x and y value from the audio waveform's amplitude.
                //You'll need to make sure that it makes sense for your animation.
                self.amplitude = getAmplitudeValueFromWaveform()

                self.animateRecordButton()
            } else {
                if let button = recordButton {
                    button.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are other approaches in regards to the audio SDK, but I haven't used it. There could be some methods in the audio SDK that can already handle that kind of thing for you.